# How can I test for a literal string in Hugo front matter?

Tags: hugo

I want to know if the value of `.field` is the same as my string literal. What's the right syntax to do that?

```html
{{ if .Params.field matchesText "random"}}
    <h1>Success!</h1>
{{ end }}
```

Obviously, I made up `matchesText`.

I found a function for [containing strings](https://gohugo.io/functions/strings.contains/) in the Hugo docs, but that's not the same as comparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `in` function

```html
{{ if in .Params.field "random"}}
    <h1>Success!</h1>
{{ end }}
```

The `in` function checks if an element is in an array, slice, or substring of a string. In some languages (e.g., Java), you have to worry about some comparisons failing because human-equivalent strings are not equivalent in memory. Thankfully, that's not problem with Hugo's `in`.